# Format Duration as ISO8601 Period with NSDateIntervalFormatter

Tags: objective-c, iso8601, nsformatter

I am trying to convert the duration between two dates to the format `"'P'yyyy'Y'M'M'd'DT'H'H'm'M's.S'S'"`. An example of my expected output is: `P0Y0M0DT0H0M0.002S` (this is port of an Android project that uses **DurationFormatUtils**).

My test case:

```
NSDateIntervalFormatter *durationFormatter = [NSDateIntervalFormatter durationFormatter];
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDate *end = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:25];
NSString *duration = [durationFormatter stringFromDate:date toDate:end];
XCTAssertTrue( [duration hasPrefix:@"P"], @"Actual String: %@", duration );
```

My formatter is defined as:

```
+ (NSDateIntervalFormatter*) durationFormatter {
    static NSDateIntervalFormatter *formatter = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        formatter = [[NSDateIntervalFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.dateTemplate = @"'P'yyyy'Y'M'M'd'DT'H'H'm'M's.S'S'";
    });

    return formatter;
}
```

When I run this, `duration` is ***3/5/2015, 16:46:20.3***. If I set the locale on the formatter to `nil` and set the date and time format to `NSDateIntervalFormatterFullStyle`, the `duration` has the following format: ***Thursday, March 5, 2015, 4:51:36 PM GMT-05:00 - Thursday, March 5, 2015, 4:52:01 PM GMT-05:00***.

How can I format the duration between two dates with ISO8601 period format (or at least as *"'P'yyyy'Y'M'M'd'DT'H'H'm'M's.S'S'"*)?

Comment: It would help if you told us what the inputs are!!!

Comment: But I don't think that NSDateIntervalFormatter does what you want it to do.  "A date interval is defined by two dates, for example, Sept 1st, 2013 - Oct 1st, 2013."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class you are using, `NSDateIntervalFormatter`, is designed to produce *intervals* of the form *date1 - date2*, not format the time difference between two dates.

To get what you are after you need to use `NSCalendar`, `NSDateComponents` and `stringWithFormat:` (or similar).

- First you need a calendar, `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]` is a good choice. (The difference between two absolute points in times can be a different when expressed in the units of a particular calendar - if that doesn't make sense don't worry, just use `currentCalendar`!)
- Next use the `components:fromDate:toDate:options:` method to obtain an instance of `NSDateComponents` which contains the number of years, days, hours etc. between your two dates.
- Finally use `stringWithFormat:` to format the components as you wish.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood what `NSDateIntervalFormatter` is for. It's for formatting an interval as a string of the form *start - end*.

It's not for formatting a duration.

You can use `NSDateComponentsFormatter` to format a duration. However, I don't know if it supports the specific format you want.

It has the convenience methods `-stringFromDate:toDate:` and `-stringFromTimeInterval:`.